# Query which will match exact word but not match compound phrases which this word is part of

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a post town field in my document.

One document is indexed with `City`.

The second one is indexed with `City Station`.

Those are different towns.

If I use match or term query with query string "City" I will get both documents as a result. Is there a way to make a query so it returns the documents which contains ONLY this query string? Need a generic way of handling those.
Comparing scores is not very reliable.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this can be easily done with `mapping` your *town* field with `"index" : "not_analyzed"` , Then with following query

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "town": {
        "value": "City"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

will match only *city* and not *city station*. Alternatively you could use [keyword analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html?q=keywo) with [lowercase token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html?q=lower) to handle case insensitive search